# select optionについて（セレクトボックス）

Tags: php, html, laravel

Lalavelのbladeでセレクトボックスを作成しようとしています。
htmlとphpで画像の上の状態を下のように選択肢を一つのみにしたいと考えております。
初期値はDBからはいやいいえを取得しています。
解れば教えて頂きたいです。
宜しくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: <select>で、2択だけどもクリックすると未選択の選択肢しか表示されない、がご希望ですか?

Comment: はいそうです。DBから取得していない方です。

Comment: 「DBの値をもとにセレクトボックスを構築する」「選択肢を一つ」をそれぞれで考えたほうが良いと思います。やることがバックエンドとフロントエンドで、独立して解決できると思います。質問者さんはどちらもできないですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にして試してみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lalavel とか blade などのことはさっぱりわかりませんが、選択されている `<option>` に `hidden` 属性を付ければ**一部のブラウザでは**お望みの結果になると思います。
デスクトップの Chrome と Firefox ではできましたが、Safari ではダメでした。

2択であればラジオボタンなどのほうが適切かもしれません。